# errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update - No encuentro la duplicacion

Tags: mysql

Hola soy nuevo en la comunidad, mi problema en especifico es que no encuentro cual es la clave duplicada que me marca el error de MySQL, estuve revisando los nombres indice por indice y aun no encuentro cual es la clave duplicada en cuestión, este error me aparece en el momento de usar el Forward Engineer de la sección de diagramas de MySQL Workbench.

> Executing SQL script in server
> ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `test2`.`asistencias` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")
> SQL Code:
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> -- Table `test2`.`asistencias`
> -- -----------------------------------------------------
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test2`.`asistencias` (
> `alumnos_id_alumno` INT(11) NOT NULL,
> `clases_id_clase` INT(11) NOT NULL,
> `presentismo` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (`alumnos_id_alumno`, `clases_id_clase`),
> INDEX `fk_alumnos_has_clases_clases1_idx` (`clases_id_clase` ASC),
> INDEX `fk_alumnos_has_clases_alumnos1_idx` (`alumnos_id_alumno`  ASC),
> CONSTRAINT `fk_alumnos_has_clases_alumnos1`
> FOREIGN KEY (`alumnos_id_alumno`)
> REFERENCES `test2`.`alumnos` (`id_alumno`)
> ON DELETE NO ACTION
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
> CONSTRAINT `fk_alumnos_has_clases_clases1`
> FOREIGN KEY (`clases_id_clase`)
> REFERENCES `test2`.`clases` (`id_clase`)
> ON DELETE NO ACTION
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
> ENGINE = InnoDB
> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
>
> SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form.
> Nothing to fetch

Comment: Porque estas crando 2 PK??

Comment: Hola que tal en este caso preciso de 2 PK (que son FK de otras tablas) para establecer una relación entre alumnos y cursos, y claro, la idea es no repetir ningún dato. Sera esta la mejor manera?